# Appending product list with custom collection

Tags: product, layout, product-list, render

I am making a small module to display a product list with content depending on the URI.

`/storeid/parts/` would be the base, with all parts/products

`/storeid/parts/mobile` would contain all parts in category **mobile -> parts
etc**..

I got to the point where it's rendering the page layout with my custom search block, but now ,how do I append a product list after the search bar?

**Current code:**

```
    $this->loadLayout();
    $items = [];
    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $url = rtrim(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(), '/');
    foreach(explode(',', $brands) as $item) {
        $name = $model->load($item)->getName();
        $items[] = [
            'url' => $url . "/" . $this->sanitize($name),
            'name' => $name
        ];
    }

    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template');
    $block->setTemplate('mavalier/parts/filter.phtml')->assign([
        'params' => $params,
        'items' => $items
    ]);
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

    $block2 = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block2);

    $this->renderLayout();
```

I feel like this is close, but it says `Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on null in C:\Users\natha\Documents\CM24\app\design\frontend\parasol\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml on line 51` which makes me think `$this->getLoadedProductcollection()` returns `null`..

How do I 'set' the `LoadedProductCollection`?

To be honest, *if you think the code i've got is wrong or isn't* how Magento is intended;

I get that, but this is more a **proof of concept** rather than production material anyway.